Follow path bone constraint has weird offset
im making a hyperjump effect in blender where I want a ship to go through a tunnel I made with a bezier circle. The tunnel is connected with a bone to a main part representing the ship. I want the tunnel to move to make it look like the ship is moving, but its actually the tunnel that moves. Im trying to achieve this by setting a follow path bone constraint and making it follow the original bezier curve that the tunnel was made with.
However, when I do this the tunnel gets this insane offset and moves way too far, which I dont know how to fix. Fixed position and follow curve are enabled in the constraint. 
I already tried setting the origin to the geometry, and clearing the position and rotation of the tunnel, to no avail. Does anyone know what im doing wrong?


Apply the scale and rotation of your curve, once done switch it to Edit mode, select all the vertices and in the N panel > Mean Radius > press 1 and Enter
